# How to use Custom Login Page in Spring Security with jdbc authentication

Tags: spring-boot, jsp, spring-security

I cannot open My Custom Login Page when I receive get request. I configured HttpSecurity but it is showing String of "login" not login.jsp.

I added below code in application.properties and jsp dependencies in pom.xml file.But anyway it is not working.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource ds(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from myusers where username = ?")
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, 1 as enabled from myusers where username = ?");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

MainController.java

```
@RestController
public class MainController {


    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/list_users")
    public String showUsers(){
        return "This is the list of users";
    }

    @RequestMapping("addUser")
    public String addUser(){

        return "User is added successfully";
    }

}
```

login.jsp

```
<h1><center>Give your login details</center></h1>
<form method="post" action="check_password">
    User name:<input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br>
    Submit <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to open my Custom login.jsp page not String. Any advice is welcome!

Comment: @You are receiving an exception or something different? How you are trying to get into the login page?

Comment: No I am not getting any exception when I use localhost:8080/list_users  url it is showing login  word only not login.jsp page

Answer (score 0):

You can understand the meaning of @RestController

Comment: Thank you sir. Instead of RestController  I needed to us @Controller